# An element array gives error "can not use property or method css with this

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using the following:

```
var panelTitleElement2 = $('div.panel-default div.panel-heading');
 panelTitleElement2[thisIndex].css("background-color", "rgb(153,0,0)");
```

I am getting following error:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'css'
```

panelTitleElement2 has 4 divs that fit the description above.  I want to only change the background color for a specific div not all of them.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Print panelTitleElement2 and thisIndex to the console and tell us what it says.

Comment: panelTitleElement2[thisIndex].currentStyle.backgroundColor = "rgb(153,0,0)";  this says in the console "nomodificationallowed".   panelTitleElement2[thisIndex] -- panelTitleElement2 undefined.  $('div.panel-default div.panel-heading')[0] gives me the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not actually dealing with the element as a JQuery object. I.e., you didn't wrap the element you're trying to reference in the '$()'. When I did exactly what you have (still referring to the element by its index, and not using '.eq()', it worked just fine.

try:

```
$(panelTitleElement2[thisIndex]).css("background-color", "rgb(153,0,0)");
```

and just to be sure, maybe try hard-coding in the index you want, in lieu of "thisIndex"

Answer (score 1):

You need `eq()` to select indexed element in jQuery collection in order to use jQuery methods on it

```
panelTitleElement2.eq(thisIndex).css("background-color", "rgb(153,0,0)");
```

When you use `$(selector)[someIndex]` it returns the actual dom node at that index in the collection

In reality this can be done on the one line

```
$('div.panel-default div.panel-heading')
         .eq(thisIndex)
         .css("background-color", "rgb(153,0,0)");
```